# How to get ID of row which is getting affected when used "REPLACE INTO" in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, last-insert-id

I am using `REPLACE INTO` command for inserting/updating record in MySQL table. However I want to get ID of row which gets affected by `REPLACE INTO`.

I used `lastInsertId()` with `INSERT INTO` but it is not useful over here because if my record already exists then by using `lastInsertId()` with `REPLACE INTO`, i'll get wrong ID.

So is there any function present in MySQL + php + PDO to get that id?

Comment: Can't you be more certain please? Providing a test case and the code to reproduce? It's quite hard to verify whatever results you may get or misinterpret, without the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since `REPLACE INTO` does a `DELETE` and then an `INSERT` you'll always get the "wrong" id with any `lastInsertId()` function (wrong as in "not the one you're probably expecting").

So you either have to live with that, look into `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` or specify what you are trying to accomplish so we can give further advice on how to proceed.

Comment: here more info http://mikefenwick.com/blog/insert-into-database-or-return-id-of-duplicate-row-in-mysql/

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just wanted to check is there any function available like lastInsertID() for Replace INTO or not.